# A list of new entries that have my preferred tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

When I go to the main page, I see a list of my tags, {template, stl, metaprogramming}.  I would like to see all the new posts in these categories on one page instead of clicking on the template tag, then clicking on the stl tag then clicking on the metaprogramming tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template+or+stl+or+metaprogramming?

Comment: yeah, i guess i could type it in manually.

Comment: You could bookmark the page. I used a bookmark with five or six tags for about a year.